# how to pass list of maps to another screen using getx in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I am trying to pass a list of maps data(getting from firebase firestore array form) from one screen to another screen using getx in flutter.

This is my code
first screen

```
final cartOrder = orderList.data.docs[index]['cartorder'];
            final orderedDate = orderList.data.docs[index]['ordered_date'];
            final delivered = orderList.data.docs[index]['delivered'];

            return SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (() {
                  Get.toNamed("/order_details?cartOrder=$cartOrder");
                  // Get.to(OrderDetails(),arguments: cartOrder);
                }),
                child:
```

This is my second screen

```
var cartOrder = Get.parameters['cartOrder'];
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cartOrder.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
```

when passing data in the first screen the data looks like this (expandable while debugging)
length of cartOrder is 2.

```
cartOrder = 
[
  {'name': 'xyz','id': '123'},
  {'name': 'abc','id': '456'}
]
```

but when receiving on the second screen not (expandable but looks like concatenating)
here length of cartorder is 4(name,id,name,id)

```
cartOrder = 
[{'name': 'xyz','id': '123'},{'name': 'abc','id': '456'}]
```

how to solve this.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this passing data like this.

```
Get.toNamed("/order_details?cartOrder=$cartOrder");
```

Try this.

```
Get.toNamed("/order_details",arguments:[cartOrder]);
```

and for getting data on second screen

```
var args = Get.arguments; // this should be placed before build method


var cartOrder = args[0]; // this should be placed after build method
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `Get.arguments`, which returns `dynamic`, `Get.parameters` returns `Map<String,String?>`. Therefore your actual data is always `String` or `null`.

So you shouldn't use `parameters` to pass complex objects. Use `arguments` instead.

If you really want to pass objects via parameters, you can serialise and send it (`toJson`) and after receiving, de-serialise it. But I wouldn't recommend it.